# Getting Business Central API access through node application

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-ad-msal, dynamics-business-central

I have an issue when trying to hit an endpoint in business central though a node application.

Using OAuth2 in postman I am able to get a desired response as seen below

[image]

This my configuration for Authorization:
[image]

but when trying to hit the same endpoint in Node using MSAL I get a 401 response.
This my configuration

[image]

I even tried taking the token generated by postman and inserted it into my application and was able to hit the endpoint with the desired response. I'm not sure what is missing from my application that's causing it to get a token that when used returns a 401 response.

What's missing from my application or is it something that I need to do in Azure or Business Central ?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the token from Postman to the token from Node to see if there are any differences? You can check the content on e.g. jwt.io

Comment: Yes I tried comparing them, there are a couple of differences some which I'm not sure are relevant or not. For example, The audience is different. For the postman token the aud is https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com and for the application token 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000

Comment: @kaspermoerch  forgot to @ you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Node, but I have used MSAL with PowerShell.

Getting the token through `MSAL.PS` (the PowerShell module for MSAL) you have to set the `Scopes` that you are requesting a token for.

In this case the scope should be `https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default` when you want to access the Business Central APIs.

Comment: That's not it, It's already specified in the application